# Sharepoint site design not applying stuck at initialisation

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-design, site-script

Sharepoint site design not applying stuck at initialisation. Below is my site script.

```
{
    "$schema": "schema.json",
    "actions": [
      {
            "verb": "createSPList",
            "listName": "Test Library 101",
            "templateType": 101
      }
    ],
    "version": 1
}
```

And in the console window, I am getting

> 404 file not found error for below URL

```
https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<site name>/_api/Microsoft.Sharepoint.Utilities.WebTemplateExtensions.SiteScriptUtility.GetSiteDesignRunStatusAndSchema
```

Please help

Comment: strange, i tried the above at my end. It took some time, but succeeded finally. Is it still happening ?

Comment: Yes it's still happening.

Comment: strange, can you try it in a different tenant and see it reproduces ?

Comment: No in another client tenant its working issue is with this tenant.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a problem on one of my tenants.

You might need to create a Microsoft Support ticket as this seems to be caused by the launching of any Site Design, even the ones out of the box.

Comment: Yes i have got very similar issue have raised with Microsoft support